# Controlling events in a Windows window without focus in Python

Tags: c#, python, winapi, click

right now I have a pretty cool script to emulate some clicks and keystrokes using Python and pretty flat WScript, but there's absolutely no way to use my computer while I run the script. My goal is for it to treat the browser like a seperate environment while not maximized, and click the things it currently clicks but in the context of this window only, not in the entire scope of my computer.

I've been at this awhile, not even really sure if it's possible here with Python. If not, could someone point me in the direction of a C# alternative? Thanks

```
import os
import sys
import time
import win32api, win32con
import win32com
import win32com.client
import random

x_pad = 0
y_pad = 1023
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')

vara = 'C:\\Python27\\cleaned.csv'

text_file = open(vara, "r" )
read_text = text_file.read()
linesList = read_text.splitlines()


##varb = vara.split(",")

##print varb

def splitll():
    for item in linesList:

 sleeptime = random.randint(60,90)
        print "sleeptime is %s" % sleeptime
        za = item.split(',')
        urlbase= 'string'
        zaa = urlbase + za[1]
        hivar = "Hi %s!" % za[3]
        zix = 'string'
        compose()
        ##to
        win32api.SetCursorPos((912,311))
        leftClick()
        time.sleep(3)
        shell.SendKeys(za[2])
        ##Subject
        win32api.SetCursorPos((904,356))
        leftClick()
        time.sleep(3)
        win32api.SetCursorPos((904,356))
        leftClick()
        time.sleep(3)
        shell.SendKeys(hivar)
        ##Body
        win32api.SetCursorPos((905,447))
        leftClick()
        time.sleep(3)
        shell.SendKeys(zix)
        print 'sending in 3'
        time.sleep(3)
        win32api.SetCursorPos((871,701))
        leftClick()
        time.sleep(sleeptime)

def main():
    screenGrab()

def leftClick():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    print "Click."     

def mousePos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos(cord[0], cord[1])


def get_cords():
    x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    print x,y

def compose():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((79,194))
    leftClick()
    time.sleep(2)

def toform():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((566,318))
    leftClick()
    time.sleep(.1)
    shell.SendKeys(varb[0])

def subform():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((563,357))
    leftClick()
    time.sleep(.1)
    shell.SendKeys(varb[1])

def bodyform():
    win32api.SetCursorPos((608,458))
    leftClick()
    time.sleep(.1)
    shell.SendKeys(varb[2])

def realmain():
    compose()
    toform()
    subform()
    bodyform()
```

Comment: Clicking without clicking? Sounds like you have to bite the bullet and use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead of those hacks.

Comment: I see you followed this tutorial too ;)  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-python-bot-that-can-play-web-games--active-11117